# Relation between Serverless Architecture and Microservices

Tags: serverless-architecture

Is the relation between Serverless Architecture and Microservices right?

- Serverless Architecture(Azure Functions or Amazon Lambda) accesses several Microservices(Amazon Elasticache or Amazon Redis Cache).
- Microservices provides functionalities that has no server scalability issue.

If it isn't, what is the right relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, serverless means functions. Functions, when bundled together, constitute a microservice. The main difference is microservices are not stateless since they run in containers, while functions are stateless since they are ephemeral. Source: https://www.simform.com/serverless-architecture-guide/

Answer (score 6):

The relationship is, Microservices can be implemented using serverless.

For example in AWS you can design a Serverless Microservice using AWS API Gateway and Lambda(Serverless compute service).

On the otherhand you can also use Serverless for DevOps. For example in AWS you can use Lambda and AWS SES to send an email to an user after build succeeds.